# Looping through range and trying (and failing) to get value from adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets

Got this function which loops through a range and, when it finds a certain text in a cell, I want to get the value of the adjacent cell.

Can't seem to get it working, keep getting:

'TypeError: Cannot find function getvalue in object Range. (line 30, file "Code")Dismiss

Error.

Anyone help?

```
    function Test (){
 var mysheet="2016";
  x=get(mysheet,"Interest");
}

function get(sheetname, txt) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname)
  var cellvalue;
  var myval;
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100;   // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 26)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var row = data[i];
      for (c=0; c< row.length; c++) 
      {
        cellvalue = row[c];
//        Logger.log ("Row: " + i + " Cell: " + c + " Cellvalue: " + cellvalue);

        if (cellvalue == txt)
            {
              Logger.log ("Row: " + i + " Cell: " + c + " Cellvalue: " + cellvalue + "Myval: " + myval);
              myval=sheet.getRange(i, c+1).getvalue();

            }
      }
      }; 

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are 0 bases, so you need to add to i & c to get the proper row and column. The length of row should be row[0].length. Also, once you find your value you can break the loop. Try this:

```
 function Test (){
 var mysheet="2016";
  x=get(mysheet,"Interest");
}
function get(sheetname, txt) {
  var sheet = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname)
  var cellvalue;
  var myval;
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 26)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var row = data[i];
      for (c=0; c< row[0].length; c++) 
      {
        cellvalue = row[c];
        if (cellvalue == txt)
        {
              i=i+1
              c=c+2
              myval=sheet.getRange(i, c).getValue()
              Logger.log( myval)
              break
            }
      }
      } 

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried the code and when I View->Logs I see the message 'No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project.' The text definitely exists in the sheet. Also, there are multiple occurrences of the text I'm looking for so I don't want to break once I've found one.

Comment: Update: If I change this:     for (c=0; c< row[0].length; c++)  to this:     for (c=0; c< row.length; c++)  ... then it does what I need it to do. Thanks,